# How to ensure Codecov test the right code coverage?

Tags: code-coverage, huggingface-transformers, codecov

I'm trying to use Codecov to get the test coverage of [Transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers). But when I look into transformers' workflows, many .yml files with pytest exist. How can I get the coverage report that accurately reflects the code coverage of transformers?

I tried Codecov and coverage.py, but I feel that Codecov reduces the time to configure the environment. However, I would like to know how to get different versions of code coverage through Codecov most efficiently. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CEO of Codecov here. I know we got Codecov working on AutoGPT, and should be possible on transformers as well.

If you have many coverage reports, codecov will merge them for you. Also, it's free because it's an open repo.

That said, I'm not exactly sure what the issue is, have you tried to enable Codecov? What type of yaml file are you referring to?

P.S. best place to ask your question is here https://github.com/codecov/feedback

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).